# Moving things outside of browser area

Tags: jquery, css, browser, positioning

Is it possible to move something (an image) out of browser area using jQuery and CSS?
So that from user's perspective the image would appear to be outside of the browser.

Comment: With _in his pc_ you actually mean _on his desktop_ may I hope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like a fake AV warning or a login box?

There are very solid reasons why this will never be possible.

So, that's a resounding NO.

Comment: thanks for answer / i just want to move my picture ... some years ago i saw something like that , i am so curious about it ... so it seems no is not the absolute answer!

Comment: Maybe you saw an applet or a popup window.